# WebApi - how is dependency injection is related to 'Unit of Work'?

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, repository-pattern

I can implement WebApi development for CRUD operation in 2 ways, 1. I can use Repository pattern + Unit of work 2. I can use Repository pattern + dependency injection

I have confusion on which approach is correct?

Need guidance on 
1. How is dependency injection related to Unit of work?
2. if I use Repository pattern + Unit of work will it cover DI also?
3. Can I use Unit of work and DI together.
4. is issue is same incase of webapi and MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Unit of work covers the scope of the DbContext. It is designed as an inject-able dependency for your repository classes and controllers. Dependency injection is a pattern for ensuring your classes accept references for services they depend on via constructor or property. They aren't exclusive of one another, rather using Unit of Work is a pattern that is complimented by Dependency Injection.

You would use an Inversion of Control container like Autofac or Unity to manage the dependencies used by your classes and manage the lifetime scope of those dependencies. For example with MVC and Web API, the IoC container would be set up to provide a dependency like the Unit of Work on a per-request basis. (meaning each request will be issued a separate instance of a Unit of Work)

Where you may want a bit more control over the unit of work, an implementation that I recommend for EF6 is Mehdi's DbContextScope pattern. (http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) With this pattern you dependency inject the ContextScopeFactory and ContextScopeLocator, then use the factory to create a context scope (unit of work), and the Repository can locate that unit of work using the Locator. This gives you more granular control of the unit of work with a using() block.

Comment: But I heard Microsoft is not recommending Unit of work to be used with EF6? Is this true? with EF6 should we discard UOW?

Comment: I've heard this mentioned, but I haven't seen any documentation stating that you should use unit of work. A DbContext can manage a transaction and work within a transaction scope so you might question if a separate unit of work implementation is necessary. However, in terms of test-ability I find that adopting a unit of work pattern leads to something easier to mock out than DbContexts and transaction scopes..